# Removing Header and keeping page number

Tags: pdftex

I want to remove page header but keeping the page number with even and odd order.
This code is sample of very large code.

```
        % !TeX spellcheck = en_US

    \documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}% Use this line for the print version of the thesis
    \usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \begin{document}
     \pagestyle{headings}
    \mainmatter
    \include{chapter1}
     \pagestyle{plain}
    \include{chapter2}

    \end{document}

% content
Chapter1


    \chapter{Chapter1}
    \label{chp:1}
    \section{XXX}
    \Blindtext
    \section{YXX}
    \Blindtext

Chapter2


    \chapter{Chapter2}
     \section{XXX}
    \Blindtext
    \section{YXa}
    \Blindtext
```

I used   \pagestyle{plain}. It works but shifts page number to to the bottom center of the page (5-8) which is wrong. I want to keep page number on left and right corner of the pages ( see page 2-4).

- Other questions are:

**why Heading of Chapter 1&2 are appearing double.

Why page number 1 is on the bottom center of the page.**

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy to redefine the `plain` pagestyle with `titleps`

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}% Use this line for the print version of the thesis
\usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{titleps}
\renewpagestyle{plain} {%
\sethead{}{}{}
\setfoot[\thepage][][]{}{}{\thepage}
}
\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\chapter{Chapter1}
\label{chp:1}
\section{XXX}
\Blindtext
\section{YXX}
\Blindtext

\chapter{Chapter2}
 \section{XXX}
\Blindtext
\section{YXa}
\Blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}% Use this line for the print version of the thesis
    \usepackage[ngerman,american]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
\makeatletter
  \def\ps@plain{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\hfill\thepage}
\def\@evenfoot{\thepage\hfill}
      \def\@evenhead{}%
      \def\@oddhead{}%
}
  \def\ps@headings{%
      \let\@oddfoot\@empty\let\@evenfoot\@empty
      \def\@evenhead{\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@oddhead{{}\hfil\thepage}%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
}
\makeatother
    \begin{document}
     \pagestyle{headings}
    \mainmatter
    \include{chapter1}
     \pagestyle{plain}
    \include{chapter2}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: Hope the modified version is fine for you...please confirm...

Comment: can you answer these**why Heading of Chapter 1&2 are appearing double. AND

Why page number 1 is on the bottom center of the page.**

Comment: why page number 1 is on the bottom center of the page - In book.cls file, chapter opening page style was defined as "plain" so as per definition page number was coming in center of the page and please provide more details or screenshot for Chapter 1&2 are appearing double...